# MediaPlayer, Android: After a while, eventhandler fires automatically, even when event has not occured

Tags: android

I have in my app a media player, to play music. When the users presses "NEXT" the next song is build and played. This all works fine until about 20-30 "NEXT" clicks the eventhandler from the media player goes haywire and keeps firing even though the event "COMPLETITION" has not occured.

Here is my function to play music:

```
    void PlayMusic(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        CurrentSongObject = WriteMetaDataToFileList(uri.ToString());

        txt_CurrentSong.Text = CurrentSongObject.SongName;
        txt_CurrentArtist.Text = CurrentSongObject.ArtistName;

        if (mediaPlayer.IsPlaying)
        {
            mediaPlayer.Stop();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, uri);

            btn_StartOrPause.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_play);
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.Stop();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(this, uri);

            Activity_Player.btn_StartOrPause.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_pause);
        }


        if (specialMode)
        {
            SeekToSongMillis(uri.ToString());
        }

        StartMediaPlayer();


        mediaPlayer.Completion += delegate
        {
            if (rndMode)
            {
                ChooseRandomNewSongAndPlay(true);
            }
            else
            {
                ChoosesNonRandomNextSongAndPlay(true);
            }
        };
    }
```

So about the last part, I sign an event handler to the event of the media player having completed the playback (the song is simply over.) But after calling this function about 25 times, the event handler keeps caling and therefore auto calling the next and next and next song. Even though no song ever completes, it just keeps skipping to the next song. Am I maybe using the handler wrong?
Please help me! :)

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have noticied something else.
after the first IF I unsigned from the event (also put the event into its own function) and this fixed the issue a bit. After a while he still goes into the event, even though he shoundlt, but then immediately leave it again and continues normally. So there is still something fishy going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out there is this beautiful reset property on the mediaplayer...

```
        mediaPlayer.Stop();
        mediaPlayer.Completion -= EventForMediaPlayBackCompletition;
        mediaPlayer.Reset();
```